# Очередь и шаблоны...

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Написал программу, которая должна добавлять элемент в конец очереди и извлекать первый... Добавление работает. А почему не работает удаление - не знаю!
Да и деструктор не работает? Что тут не так?

```
template < class SType > class stack {
 public:char *p[MAX];
 public:
    int spos;
    int rpos;
    stack() {
        rpos = 0;
        spos = 0;
    }

    char qretrieve(void);
    void enter(void), qstore(char *q), review(void), delete_ap(void);
    //~stack();
};

int main(void)
{
    stack < char >c;
    char s[80];
    register int t, i = 0;
    char *k[MAX];
    for (t = 0; t < MAX; ++t)
        k[t] = NULL;    /* иницилизировать массив
                   пустыми указателями */

    for (;;) {
        printf("In (E), Spisok (L), Rem (R), Quit (Q): ");
        gets(s);
        *s = toupper(*s);

        switch (*s) {
        case 'E':
            c.enter();
            break;
        case 'L':
            c.review();
            break;
        case 'R':
            c.delete_ap();
            break;
        case 'Q':
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Вставка в очередь новой встречи. */
template < class SType > void stack < SType >::enter(void)
{
    char s[256], *p;

    do {
        printf("Vvedi stroky %d: ", spos + 1);
        gets(s);
        if (*s == 0)
            break;    /* запись не была произведена */
        p = (char *)malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
        if (!p) {
            printf("Lost memory.\n");
            return;
        }
        strcpy(p, s);
        if (*s)
            qstore(p);
    } while (*s);
}

/* Просмотр содержимого очереди. */
template < class SType > void stack < SType >::review(void)
{
    register int t;

    for (t = rpos; t < spos; ++t)
        printf("%d. %s\n", t + 1, p[t]);
}

/* Удаление встречи из очереди. */
template < class SType > void stack < SType >::delete_ap(void)
{                //char *p;
    //register int t;
    //char *p;
    //for(t=rpos; t < spos; ++t)
    // printf("%d. %s\n", t+1, p[t]);
    //if((*p=qretrieve())==NULL) return; 
    //printf("%s\n", p);
}

/* Вставка встречи. */
template < class SType > void stack < SType >::qstore(char *q)
{
    if (spos == MAX) {
        printf("List Full\n");
        return;
    }
    p[spos] = q;
    spos++;
}

/* Извлечение встречи. */
template < class SType > char stack < SType >::qretrieve(void)
{
    if (rpos == spos) {
        printf("Net vstrech.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    rpos++;
    return p[rpos - 1];
}
```

Comment: А где вы удаляете? Где деструктор?

Comment: Закоменчен-т.к. не работает да и функция удаления не работает(

Comment: //~stack(); -в классе.

/* Удаление встречи из очереди. */
template < class SType > void stack < SType >::delete_ap(void)
{               
   char *p;
   
   if((*p=qretrieve())==NULL) return; 
   printf("%s\n", p);
}- это не рабочая функция

Comment: Не понял смысла использовать тут шаблон.

Comment: Я вижу метод удаления, но не вижу чтобы вы там что-то удаляли! Ме од деструктора тоже не видно. Если используете шаблонный класс, то уж замените все ваши чары на шаблонное имя.

Comment: Смысла использовать шаблон я тоже не вижу... Препод требует...
Мой метод удаления просто не работает... Не знаю как его реализовать(

Comment: @Alerr, если это учебное задание, то с 90% вероятности, у вас не примут такую структуру класса!<br>Вам надо сделать класс универсального стека, с 2 методами: push/pop. метод enter - точно не классовый!

Comment: Можете дать нормальный материал где можно посмотреть про очереди с использованием классов.шаблонов?

Comment: Пробовал использовать стандартные функции для работы с очередью, но не могу понять как сказать классу-шаблону, что они стандартные!???

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




template <class string> class stack{
queue<string> a;
public:
 stack(){}
//~stack(); 
 void push(), pop(int a), front();
};
 
template <class SType> void stack<SType>::push(int a)
{
}
 
int main(void)
{
 stack<queue<string>> q;
 int i;
 for(i=0; i<10; i++)
  q.push();
  
 getchar();
  return 0;
}

Comment: Подключить нужные заголовки.

Comment: Инклуде<.....>- само собой подключал...

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того, чего Вы хотите добиться. Если чтобы работало - то используйте для стека класс list<>. Если научиться - то обратитесь к учебникам или сформулируйте вопрос почетче.

К сожалению, представленный код несколько неграмотен по оформлению, архитектуре и т.п. Искать причину неработоспособности подобного кода - занятие достаточно неблагодарное. Его нужно переписывать полностью.

Прошу прощения, если моё сообщение показалось Вам обидным или несправедливым. Я бы с удовольствием Вам помог, но в данном вопросе это затруднительно :-(.